# Unable to play FIFA 2022 online matches on Nintendo Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-online, fifa-22

I've been playing *FIFA 2022* on a Nintendo Switch, for many months, the game and console are updated to the latest version, I have a Nintendo Online subscription and inside the game, I am able to access other online functions, but matching people online has become a nightmare.

Here is an example of the last 10 attempts to connect. Only 2 were successful (see in the image how Nick does not even appear on the list, is because there were actually more attempts between Nick and Michel):

[image: screenshot of image described above]

**Symptoms**

Whenever I try to play online season after finding a rival it says:

- Invalid Squad Templates (your templates don't match the other player)
- Connection lost to rival, please start a new search

**Things I have tried**

- Playing at different times of day
- Moving closer to the router
- Restarting the game
- Reinstalling the game
- Moving the game from SD card to internal memory
- Going to Profile -> Erase and erasing all info, including Squad Templates
- Downloading new Squad Templates

I have asked the same on the [EA Question website](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Technical-Issues/FIFA-22-Online-Seasons-Always-disconnected-or-Invalid-Squad/m-p/11105863#M22588) and after 1 month there is not a single answer.

What can be happening? How can I solve this? What other information do you need to help me find the solution for this?

Here is my network test from Cloudflare:
[image: network test from Cloudflare screenshot]
I have considered stopping playing this game since career mode and offline games get boring.

Comment: You mention moving closer to your Wi-Fi. Have you tried playing it in docked mode using a wired connection (via USB 3.0 to ethernet adapter)?

Comment: I did not know that wired mode was possible in that way, my switch is in docked mode less than 3 ft away from modem, the thing is that I was able to play for many months using the same WIFI, same ISP at the same distance. I have removed the game because last night in 1.5 hours was able to play just 1 online game and have also asked for a 50% refund (probably not getting it). If I re-install the game I will try your suggestion - thanks

Comment: @LeoS. - The USB/LAN adapter that I have does not seem compatible, Don't plan on buying one just for this tests - https://www.wpri.com/reviews/br/electronics-br/gaming-accessories-br/best-nintendo-switch-lan-adapter/

Answer (score 2):

After asking EA for support 4 times, and never getting an answer, I decided to ask Nintendo support. They did not say much about troubleshooting my issue, and initially said that my refund could not be asked because I have played the game for so many weeks.

The person was very clear that he did not have the permission to ask for refund, but he created a ticket for team with higher permissions and provided me with a toll-free number to call.

**I called Nintendo yesterday and GOT A FULL REFUND**, the reason behind that is that I have already done all the troubleshooting possible, and that if EA was not providing support for these game they could offer the refund.

Very happy with Nintendo support, very disappointed with EA support, they consider Nintendo Switch a forgotten kingdom.

**Regarding the connectivity issues:** my theory is that is a server side issue, probably those servers are not enough or have a configuration issue that makes connecting looking for a game a nightmare

I have not yet found a page to check status of FIFA 22 servers for Nintendo Switch, here are some [for Playstation and Xbox](https://updatecrazy.com/check-fifa-22-server-status-here-fifa-22-servers-down/).

And someone is keeping [a log](https://www.fifaultimateteam.it/en/fifa-maintenance-status-server-ultimate-team-live-update/) about the issues that are reported.

Comment: Yeah, sorry you had to get to that. And yeah, EA support sucks. My Apex account was hacked and I posted a ticket last year. Its pretty clear its not me (In canada, sucked, stopped playing, suddenly there is 3 games from Vietnam where i drop 30 bombs). Wrote a ticket to get unbanned. That ticket went unanswered for now a year.

Comment: I have been playing FIFA probably for more than 7 years, when there is no support is the end for me. I wish there was some sort of petition to sign to fix the lack of support from EA